# Why can we cast bool to str?

Tags: python, truthiness

We know how `bool()` acts on various python objects such as `str`, `int`, `list`.

This is a question about the reverse.

You can cast bool to int as

```
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
```

which I think kinda makes sense, but with string we get

```
>>> str(False)
'False'
>>> str(True)
'True'
```

which I don't get, as firstly it seems to imply some relation between `False` and `'False'`, which only seems relevant at the code level. If what is written in code is to be treated this way, how does this work ...

```
>>> str(not True)
'False'
```

Second, it's not obvious it's for consistency, as

```
>>> bool(str(False))
True
```

My question is ... is there a reason we're allowed to cast `bool` to `str` in this way? `list` for example won't allow it ...

```
>>> list()
[]
>>> bool()
False
>>> bool(list())
False
>>> list(bool())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You can't print it if it isn't a string. By the way, `print` automatically converts items to their string representation by calling the `__str__` method, which is also what an str call delegates to.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what the `list(bool())` is supposed to represent.  The list constructor explicitly states it takes an iterable, which `bool()` is not.  It doesn't seem related to the other examples.

Comment: Why would `str(not True)` not work? `not True` is `False`, and converting that to a printable string results in `False`. It's nothing different than `str(1+1)` yielding `2` and not `1+1`.

Comment: `print(str(not True))` works the same way as `print(2 * 4)`: the expression is evaluated, then `str(result)` is printed

Comment: You can do `str(True)` because `True` has a [`__str__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). `bool(str(False))` is `True` because non-empty strings are [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false/39984051#39984051)

Comment: Regarding your `bool(str(...))` example, typecasts were never intended to be bijections. Consider `float(int(3.5))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For debugging. If you can't cast a thing to a string, you can't print it. If you want to print a data structure for debugging, you need to be able to cast each element to a string. [That's what `str` is documented to do](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str)...

> Return a string containing a nicely printable representation of an object.

---

> *If what is written in code is to be treated this way, how does this work ...*
>
> ```
> >>> str(not True)
> 'False'
> ```

`not True` resolves to `False` which is then passed to `str`. It's similar to how with `foo(1 + 1)` `foo` receives 2.

---

> *Second, it's not obvious it's for consistency, as*
>
> ```
> >>> bool(str(False))
> True
> ```

Casting is not guaranteed to round trip. Examples are `int(float(2.34))` or `int(unichr(97))`.

There's an important difference between converting something to a string for humans, which is what `str` does, and converting something to a string for [marshalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) which must round trip. There are specialized packages like [`marshal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html) or [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html?highlight=json) for marshalling.

But casting is the wrong way to think about `bool` and `str` in Python. As above, `str` returns a printable representation, not a machine-readable one. `bool` is for asking "what is the truthiness of this expression"? [From the docs...](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bool)

> x is converted using the standard truth testing procedure.

`"True"` and `"False"` are both true. If they added a special case just for `bool` that would be very inconsistent.

Comment: On round-tripping: I was searching for another example that would make it obvious, but `float(str(-0.0))` yields ... `-0.0`. So much for that.

Comment: i get the round trip thing, e.g. `int(bool(5))` is 1. `bool` maps to two values so it can't be round-trip

Comment: `bool` is not casting, read what it's supposed to do: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool

Comment: @usr2564301 `list(str([1,2]))` is `['[', '1', ',', ' ', ']']`. `bytes(str(b'abc'))` is an exception. Plenty of things don't round-trip.

Comment: @usr2564301 `int(float(1.2))`

Comment: @Schwern `"True"` and `"False"` are both  f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ **true**. (Edit submitted)

Answer (score 3):

`str()` and `bool()` are not "casts", they're constructors (type objects). Calling `str(x)` for any value `x` will construct a new `str` object with its value initialized (somehow) from `x`. There is no implied relationship between the two objects; `str(x)` could return anything as long as it is a `str` object.

Basically: stop thinking of Python as having "casts" like other languages you may be used to. Constructors are just another kind of callable, and the general rule is for each type to do something sensible with the argument(s) passed to the constructor. In the case of `str()`, it delegates to the `__str__` special method if present, which means that `bool` objects return the strings `'True'` and `'False'` because that's what the `bool` type decided to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what is the problem with `str(True)` being `'True'`? That's quite the expected.

Now, if you convert boolean to integer, it's obvious that the result must be a number.

And, naturally, `not True` evaluates to `False`. That is `str(False)`, then: `'False'`.

About the `bool()` function, it's supposed to return `True` for anything that is not empty, zero, None or False.

So any string that is not `''` fits this and returns `True`. See more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth

Comment: "About the bool() function, it's supposed to return True for anything that is not empty or undefined or False." is wrong. First, you can't call it on something undefined (doing anything with something undefined is an exception). Second, the rule is that it returns true for anything that is not empty, false, _or `None`, or zero_.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very limited set of things considered `False` in Python:

- None
- False
- zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
- any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
- any empty mapping, for example, {}.
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False

So if you do `bool(something)` it will only return `False` for those items. Everything else in Python is `True` including string representations of falsy things: `'0'` `'False'`, `'None'` etc because the string itself is `True`.